# only continue loop if method has finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency

I have a `for/in` loop like so:

```
for(NSString *paymentId in success){
   [self getPaymentDetails:paymentId];
}
```

The method `getPaymentDetails` is asynchronous. How do I create a completion block to only continue the for/in loop if the method has finished?

- details

the method `getPaymentDetails` looks like this:

```
-(void)getPaymentDetails:(NSString *)paymentId{

  PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
  [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"getpaymentdetails"
                     withParameters:@{@"objectid": paymentId, @"userid": currentUser.objectId}
                              block:^(NSDictionary *success, NSError *error) {
                                if(success){
                                  NSDictionary *payment = success;
                                  NSString *amount = [payment objectForKey:@"amount"];
                                  if (![amount isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                                    [self.amountArray addObject:amount];
                                  }
                                  else {
                                    [self.amountArray addObject:@""];
                                  }

                                  NSString *currency = [payment objectForKey:@"currency"];
                                  if (![currency isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                                    [self.currencyArray addObject:currency];
                                  }
                                  else {
                                    [self.currencyArray addObject:@""];
                                  }

                                  [self.tableView reloadData];

                                } else{

                                  NSLog(@"Error logged getpaymentdetails: %@", error);
                                }
                          }];

}
```

The definition of "finished" is hereby defined when the amount as well as the currency has been stored in the array. Or in other words: when the code block has reached the end of the method for that specific `paymentId`

Comment: the method getPaymentDetails changes some variable? In that case you can put a while(myVar==nil){ //empty } ^{YourBlockHere} myVar=nil

Comment: @iZabala A tight poling loop on any thread is a bad idea.  It is particularly bad on the main thread

Comment: There is no general definition of when an asynchronous method is "complete." It entirely depends on what the method does, and what you would like "complete" to mean. Absent any details, the simplest answer is to modify `getPaymentDetails` to be synchronous, and move this loop off the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys.I updated the the question to provide some more context as for what I'm looking. Making the method synchronous is an interesting thought, but it has it downsides and if possible, I'd like to keep it asynchronous.

Comment: Here is a solution to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031267/sendasynchronousrequest-makes-ui-freezes/20142781#20142781  If you are sufficiently creative you can recognize that the kind of problem is exactly the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *semaphores* for this kind of synchronisation. Semaphores are a basic building block in concurrency and provide among other things non-busy waiting. GCD provides semaphores through `dispatch_semaphore-create`, `dispatch_semaphore_signal` and `dispatch_semaphore_wait`.

In very general outline first create a semaphore:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
```

then in your loop wait on this semaphore:

```
for(NSString *paymentId in success)
{
   [self getPaymentDetails:paymentId];
   dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // wait for call to signal completion
}
```

and then at the appropriate place in your background block signal completion with:

```
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
```

For more details on the API see the manual (`man` command), for semaphores find a book (or the internet).

HTH

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work a lot already. I don't know much about this topic so I'll do some reading into it. However, my cloud function seems to take forever now, and the block inside it never gets called. Do you know what causes that?